# Rails linking form submission to object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, post, submission

In a rails project I have two entities, Users and Institutions, they have a many-to-many relationship.

The views for them are set up to create new users and institutions but I want to have another view for linking the two.
In rails console all I have to do is

```
myuser.institutions << the_institution_i_just_created
```

The controller can do some of the work but how do I handle the submissions and the forms?  I want to use a selection box so that the input is limited to the Institutions already in existence.

```
<select id="institution_selection" name="institution_sel">
<% selections = []
   Institution.all.each do |institution|
      pair = [institution.name, institution.id]
      selections.concat([pair])
   end 
   %>
   <%= options_for_select(selections) %>
</select>
```

So the question in summary is how do I map this submission to an object so that in the controller I can do add it to the relation?

The solution was:

Alright, so this is the solution I came up with, I'm sure there is a better way to go about it and I'll continue to look into it but at least I got something close to what I was aiming for

```
def test
  if !session[:user]
     redirect_to users_path, notice: "Please login first"
  end
  if params[:institution]
     @user = User.find(session[:user])
     @institution = Institution.find(params[:institution][:id])
     @user.institutions << @institution
     redirect_to @user, notice: "Institution was successfully added "
  end
end
```

and for the view

```
<%= form_tag("/users/test", :method => "post") do %>
<%= collection_select :institution, :id, Institution.all, :id, :name %>
<%= submit_tag("Search") %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `collection_select`

```
<% from for @instancevar do |form| %>
     <%= form.collection_select :institution_id, Institution.all, :id, :name %> 
     # Do other stuff....
<% end %>
```

Comment: That worked really well for the selection box!  A lot simpler than the way I was going about it but how do I link (at)instancevar above to something I can use in the controller.

so in the controller how can I access that

Comment: what exactly do you mean with "link to sth."?

Comment: I got pretty close, I changed the "question" because I'm not allowed to post my own answer until I have more reputation...

Comment: Okay dude this would work but I suggest you to read a rails book because you are doing the typical mistakes of a php coder that switched to rails. In my opinion "Agile Web Development with Rails" is the best beginner book and after that you Should read "The Rails 3 Way" which covers as good as all questions about Rails.

Comment: Well, I did eventually rip this completely down.  I made a separate controller for logins.  I've got two books on development in Rails on their way now but I will be sure to add those two to my collection. And yes, I am a PHP coder.